# How to capture subdomain in nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to capture `subdomain` and rewrite URL with `/subdomain`, For example `bhautik.bhau.tk` rewrite to `bhau.tk/bhautik`.

I also https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax tried group syntax

Here is my `nginx` ingress config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: subdomain
  namespace: subdomain
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$sub
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      set $prefix abcd;
      if ($host ~ ^(\w+).bhau\.tk$) {
        // TODO? 
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$prefix/$uri
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.bhau.tk"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: subdomain
            port:
              number: 80
```

How do I capture subdomain from $host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want a redirect instead of rewrite. Here is the `server-snippet` you need:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  if ($host ~ ^(?<subdom>\w+)\.(?<basedom>bhau\.tk)$) {
    return 302 https://$basedom/$subdom/ ;
  }
```

If you really want a rewrite where the URL that the user sees remains unchanged but instead the request will be routed to a subpath served by the same service:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  if ($host ~ ^(?<subdom>\w+)\.(?<basedom>bhau\.tk)$) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$subdom/$1 ;
  }
```

Remove the `rewrite-target` annotation that specifies `$prefix`. You don't need it.

The `?<capturename>` and `$capturename` pair is the trick you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        if ($host ~ "bhautik.bhau.tk")
        {
            rewrite ^ https://bhau.tk$host permanent;
        }
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: bhau.tk
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 3000
        path: (/|$)(.*)
```